# How to create datagrid columns from multiple records using LinqtoSql?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, datagrid

I have a sql table and I want each record to be a datagrid column
And another sql table with multiple records related to each fieldID. I would like to display each value in the appropiate column of a datagrid using linq

```
Example  data:
tbl_fields:

FieldID   |  FieldName
1         |   First Name
2         |   Last Name 
3         |   State  

tbl_records
RecID    |   FieldID     |   Value
1               1            John               
1               2            Doe               
1               3            NY                
2               1            Melissa
2               2            Rose               
3               1            Charlie
3               2            Brown
3               3            CA  

Display like this
RecID    |   First Name  | Last Name  | State
1              John             Doe          NY
2              Melissa          Rose         null
3              Charlie          Brown        CA
```

Any suggestions?
Thank you!

edit:
This works ok but what if i don't know FieldNames before hand or more FieldNames area added?

```
var data = (from d in db. tbl_records
                group d by d.RecID into g
                select new
                {
                    Id = g.Key,
             FirstName = g.Where(d => d.FieldName == "First Name").FirstOrDefault().Value,
         LastName = g.Where(d => d.FieldName == " Last Name").FirstOrDefault().Value,
     State= g.Where(d => d. State == "State").FirstOrDefault().Value,
               });
```

Comment: are you familiar with Linq, I would use the Database Designer to have it generate the SQL Joins for you .. then if you have the Linq tool that could generate the Linq Statement for you passing / having it convert the SQL for you to a valid linq statement.. that would help you to learn / understand Linq.. the tool is called LinqPad here is a link to several other cool Linq Tools http://www.thinqlinq.com/default/LINQ-Tools.aspx

Comment: +1 for at least taking the time to format your data for the rest of us.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I am very familiar with linq but i'm not familiar displaying pivot data with linq

Answer (score 0):

you can use pivot query. your query will generate columns automatically.

for oracle
http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=506

for sql server
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1019/crosstab-queries-using-pivot-in-sql-server-2005/

Comment: Can Pivot be used if I don't know the fieldNames? for example in my example I have "First Name" "Last Name" "State" other fields could be added eventually "address" "city", how can use Pivot using all the possible fields names without knowing before hand? 

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can add a dbml, add to this file the tables you want. then do somthing like:

```
    var dc = new YourdataContext();
    yourGrid.DataSource = dc.YourTable.Select( t => new {  
                                                    t.Property1, 
                                                    t.RelationTable.Property2, 
                                                    etc...                     
                                                  } );
   yourGrid.DataBind();
```

and add this in the **page_load** or **page_init**

Hope this helps.
Cheers.